# RequestStore vs memoization

Tags: ruby

I have a problem about understanding [RequestStore](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) objects and ruby [memoization](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/). I want to find the difference between two. One of the main difference I want to know is the life span of these variables.

I have read articles and blogs and it seems like both of them spans for one request/response cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Lifespan

Memoized value can survive across multiple request/response cycles if you do it on a global object (for example, the kind of objects you may create in initializers).

RequestStore values are explicitly cleared at the end of the cycle.

### Scope

Memoized value is only accessible via reference to its enclosing object.

RequestStore values are globally accessible (simply because `RequestStore` is a constant, visible from everywhere).